# Prevent static IP address from resetting to default

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have a CentOS 6 machine configured with a static IP address in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
IPADDR=192.168.1.100
```

If I manually change the address `iconfig eth0 10.1.2.3` then unplug the cable, the address will reset to 192.168.1.100 when it's plugged back in (you typically have to wait a few seconds before plugging it back in).  I would rather it keep 10.1.2.3.

I haven't observed this behavior in CentOS 5 but it's present in 6.

Is there a way to prevent it from resetting the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

stop network manager, which is resetting your network when it detects the network connection based on your static configuration, if you do not want to permanently change it by editing ifcfg-eth0.